# When to use getX method

Tags: c#, java, properties

Coming from a C# background we use properties for something that would not take long to retrieve and a `getX` method if something would take long ([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx)). In Java, since there are no properties, do you use `getX` for both cases or is there some other convention to indicate a quick access from a not so quick access (other than documenting it)?

**Edit:**
For example would you use a different naming convention for a time consuming get operation like database access or also use the `getX` naming convention?

Comment: In Java, it is not expected that the caller should know if a method will take a long time and have to call a different method if it might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `getX()` methods are considered to be quick access methods and database-backed methods should be `findX()` or `loadX()` or something along those lines, but as far as I know there's no global agreement over it. Even the "getters should be quick" rule isn't adhered to sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The `getX` convention comes from [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) specification. More recently, usage of [POJOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (Plain Old Java Objects) has become very popular since many frameworks manipulate your objects using getters and setters, including [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) and [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29).

More specifically:

- `getX` for a nonboolean `X` (getter)
- `isX` for a boolean `X` (getter)
- `setX` for any value of `X` (setter)

If you won't use a framework that requires usage of POJOs, then by all means name your methods so you know what they do at first glance.

Comment: I'm aware of the `isX` for boolean return types. My focus is more on the naming based on the speed of the access though than the return type. In other words: should it still be `getX` if it will takes some time to process.

Comment: @Cornelius: I'd say, no. `getX` should be used for basic access to a variable. For something that takes time (db access, computation, processing, etc...), use an appropriate naming scheme.

Comment: I never liked the isX convention for booleans, it seems smelly to me; why break a perfectly clean pattern for only slightly better readability?  Actually often times its not anymore readable at all!  And typing object.<ctrl><space> in Eclipse misses the booleans!  Sorry for the tangent, its just always bothered me..  :)

Comment: @romacafe: I share the same feelings. I always use `getX`, since it's simply more consistent. Using `isX` just for boolean makes boolean seem like a black sheep in the family.

Comment: @Cornelius: Chose the style based on how you like to READ your code -- not 'speed' concerns. The JVM is very good at optimizing the common cases; it's likely that simple property access by a getter will simply be inlined at runtime.

Comment: @Uriah the naming self is not the optimization, in .Net the convention usually allow a person consuming an API to see quickly if a method will take long. See the link in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation and exactly what you're doing - for example, you might use `loadX`, `fetchX`, `computeX` - or sometimes just `getX` as for normal "cheap" properties.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, create a private member field for local access to your property and a getter / setter for external access.

Lots of 3rd party libs such as Spring rely on public methods for dependency injection (inversion of control), and and aspect oriented programming so using getter / setters facilitates that style of programming.

For example, Spring might be used to associate two objects together. Or you might use AOP to put some caching behaviour around a somewhat expensive get operation.

It also allows you to set breakpoints when the property is changed or retrieved, add logging etc. which can be useful for debugging.